# How I can get the child of a ViewGroup in Cordova with findViewById()?

Tags: java, android, cordova, android-framelayout, viewgroup

i have a cordova application and create one FrameLayout and add this to the Parent View.

```
cordovaParent = (FrameLayout) cordova.getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

Here:

```
   private void addFramelayout(int tag){
        final Rect rect = new Rect(x,y,x+width-1,y+height-1);
        final FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(thisActivity);

        frameLayout.setId(tag);
        frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top);
        params.leftMargin = rect.left;
        params.topMargin = rect.top;

        frameLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

        if(frameLayout.getParent()!=null) {
            ((ViewGroup)frameLayout.getParent()).removeView(frameLayout);
        }

        cordovaParent.addView(frameLayout);

    }
```

Here is my execute:

```
cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    if(id==0){
                        addFramelayout(containerId1); //100

                        int d = cordovaParent.getChildCount();

                        FrameLayout layout =  (FrameLayout) thisActivity.findViewById(containerId1); //here i get the error


                    }

                }
            });
```

I check with debuger and see that the parnt has a new child framelayout.

The Error:

```
org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebView cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout
```

Comment: Are you using cordova 4.0 ?

Comment: yes.........................